# how do I make a dynamically imported module available in another module or file?

Tags: python, import, eval

I have 3 files a.py, b.py, c.py

I am trying to dynamically import a class called "C" defined in c.py from within a.py
and have the evaluated name available in b.py

python a.py is currently catching the NameError. I'm trying to avoid this and create an
instance in b.py which calls C.do_int(10)

a.py

```
import b

#older
#services = __import__('services')
#interface = eval('services.MyRestInterface')

# python2.7
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('c')
interface = eval('module.C')

# will work
i = interface()
print i.do_int(10)

# interface isn't defined in b.py after call to eval
try:
  print b.call_eval('interface')
except NameError:
  print "b.call_eval('interface'): interface is not defined in b.py"
```

---

b.py

```
def call_eval(name):
  interface = eval(name)
  i = interface()
  return i.do_int(10)
```

---

c.py

```
class C(object):
  my_int = 32
  def do_int(self, number):
    self.my_int += number
    return self.my_int
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems rather convoluted. Can you be more specific about the problem; perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`interface` only exists in `a`'s namespace. You can put a reference to the interface into `b`'s namespace like this

```
b.interface = interface
try:
  print b.call_eval('interface')
except NameError:
  print "b.call_eval('interface'): interface is not defined in b.py"
```

I'm not sure why you're not just passing the interface to `call_eval` though

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there should be a better solution by totally avoiding this.

But this could do the trick:

a.py:

```
shared_variables = {}
import b

import c
shared_variables['C'] = c.C

b.do_something_with('C')
```

b.py:

```
from __main__ import shared_variables

def do_something_with(name):
    print(shared_variables[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

If a.py already loads the class, I fail to see the reason to pass it by name. Instead, do

```
# b.py
def call_eval(klass):
  j = klass()
  return i.do_int(10)
```

and, in a.py, do

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('c')
interface = getattr(module, 'C')
b.call_eval(interface)
```